# Porque adicionar um ng-click no corpo do html não funcionar?

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho o sequinte codigo:

```
<div ng-show="d.box" class="box-red">
   <img src="images/boxred.jpeg">
</div>
<div>
   <i class="button" ng-click="d.box = !d.box"></i>
</div>
```

Quando clico no icone (que é um botao) aparece um quadrado vermelho na tela, pois a váriavel do Controller: `d.box` é setada de `false` para `true`, mas se não houver ng-click e eu adicionar manualmente no inspecionar não funciona. Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Como assim "adicionar manualmente no inspecionar"?

Comment: Abrir o codigo no inspecionar com o botão direito ir no html e adicionar manualmente o ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer algo como:

```
<div ng-show="d.box" class="box-red">
    <img src="images/boxred.jpeg">
</div>
<div>
    <i class="button" ng-click="toggleFunc()"></i>
</div>
```

E no controller você criar uma função que faça a mudança de estado da variável no scope

```
app.controller('myCtlr', function($scope){
    $scope.d.box = false; //garante que a var será criada
    $scope.toggleFunc = function(){
        if($scope.d.box) {
            $scope.d.box = false;
        } else {
            $scope.d.box = true;
        }
    }
});
```